# No SSL caused by mixed content in ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, ssl, heroku

I have an APP written in Ruby. The authentication is made through Facebook-Graph_API.

I am using an SSL certificate which is validated through Globe SSL.

The connection is encrypted and almost everything is working fine. BUT!

The connection is insecure caused by mixed content. The pictures which the app is loading are coming through http. But I need this from an https source.

I found here:

[Graph API for Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api)

that I have to use something like this:

> return_ssl_resource => true

But I don´t know at which Position I have to paste this!

Does anybody have an example or experience with this? I you need further Information please let me know.

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you're requesting the data from Facebook that contains the images you're going to display, append `return_ssl_resource=true` as a query parameter to the request you make.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<UID>/picture?return_ssl_resources=true
```